Como puedo dibujar una estela que siga la orbita de un cuerpo en THREE js?
tengo una clase planeta con un metodo para actualizar la orbita de estos que genera un cuerpo que sigue las coordenadas actualizadas por la funcion,
lo que necesito es que una pequeña estela o linea marque la orbita de este planeta
esta funcion es la responsable de actualizar la orbita de mis planetas
    actualizarOrbita(angleOffset, speed, amplitude) {
    const angle = Date.now() * speed * 0.001 + angleOffset;
    const x = Math.cos(angle) * this.orbitRadius * amplitude;
    const y = Math.cos(angle) * this.orbitRadius;
    const z = Math.sin(angle) * this.orbitRadius * amplitude;

    this.solidSphere.position.x = x;
    this.solidSphere.position.z = z;

    if (this.direction == 1) {
        this.solidSphere.position.y = y;
    } else {
        this.solidSphere.position.y = -y;
    }

    this.glowSphere.position.copy(this.solidSphere.position); // Mover el borde con glow junto al centro sólido
    this.solidSphere.rotation.y += 0.01;
    // Actualizar posición de la línea para seguir la órbita
}

}

Me imagino que quieres algo como lo siguiente
const orbitPoints = [];
orbitPoints.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z));
if (orbitPoints.length > 100) {
    orbitPoints.shift();
}
   orbitLineGeometry.setFromPoints(orbitPoints);

x,y,z son las coordenadas que proporcionaste en tu código.
